# Call a function from another ViewController found an error

Tags: ios, swift, function

Im trying to call a function from another ViewController but everytime I try it send me an error: : unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

the code Im using is something like this.

```
    FirstViewController one:

   func showup(){
     runoutbut.hidden = false
}
```

And Im calling it from another ViewController with this function:

```
func go(){
   FirstViewController().showup()
}
```

and everytime I active it...  the program send me this error...  "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Any idea on how I can fix it?  thanks in advance...

Comment: You need the reference to the existing `FirstViewController` instance instead of creating a new one. Pass it using the protocol / delegate pattern or via a segue.

Comment: Your `runoutbut` button is part of your `FirstViewController`. The button loads when the view loads. Since the `FirstViewController`'s view has not loaded, the button has not loaded either, and therefore will be nil

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do directly make static method then call it directly with class name

```
  FirstViewController one:

  static func showup(){
     runoutbut.hidden = false
}
```

Comment: Then `runoutbut` which is obviously an instance variable or Outlet is supposed to be static, too. Using static methods to avoid the effort of writing  a protocol and appropriate delegate methods is not good programming habit.

Comment: you are right , I only show a single way of programming , there are many

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html) in the section Type Methods, you need to make your method a Type Method or if you want it to be and instance method get a reference to the existing instance of FirstViewController.